# Failure to connect to Microsoft SQL Server at first attempt

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have an Access accdb file in which all the tables are linked (not imported) to a Microsoft SQL Server (2008 R2). When I Load the program I get this error message:[image]

Now, after clicking OK I get "SQL Server login" screen, where "use trusted connection" is checked. My server doesn't use "SQL and windows authentication mode" - I don't know why it is checked. If I uncheck it and enter my username+password everything works fine until the next time I load the application.

I checked my server's log and every time the connection fails I get two errors: 17806 followed by 18452. It is important to say that my station and the server are on the same network domain.

Any ideas? Thanks

SOLVED: When selecting which tables to link, there was a 'save password' checkbox on the right. Cheking ot solved the problem

Comment: Did you try relinking the tables using the linked table manager. Do you have an ODBC DSN on the computer you are running the application which you can use from the linked table manager? When you test the connection from the ODBC connection manager in Windows, is the connection successful?

Comment: The answer is yes I did try the linked table manager, I do have a DSN file and the test I ran was successful

Comment: Does the DSN File use a trusted connection or a SQL Server Login (with SQL Server user name and password)?

Comment: Yes it does, double checked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of errors can be avoided by choosing the "Save password" option of the link tables dialog:

[image: link tables]

However, a much cleaner solution is to configure the SQL Server and its database to use integrated Windows authentication whenever possible.