# How to save ms access linked table via odbc password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I'm working on a MS Access application redevelopment to asp.net C#. I’m thinking to use the same MS Access DB as backend for my asp.net but it contains some linked tables via ODBC and it requesting authentication each time it tries to connect to MS Access.

the question is, how I can save the ODBC password in MS Access in order to avoid the authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if you can delete and re-create the table links in the Access database using the "Save password" option as shown in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15882040/2144390).

Comment: @GordThompson if i remove and re-add ms access linked tables will it affect on the relationships? thanks